# Converting one object to another typescript

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I have one object like this

```
jsonOne = [{
    "customer": {
      "emailAddress": "test@gmail.com"
    },
    "recommendationProductDetails": [{
      "productId": "4288",
      "title": "Title 1",
      "imageWebAddress": "http://url.com/GetImage/2956",
      "webAddress": "http://url.com/",
      "description": "Description 23"
    }, {
      "productId": "8888",
      "title": "Title 8",
      "imageWebAddress": "http://url.com/GetImage/2333",
      "webAddress": "http://url.com/",
      "description": "Description 55"
    }]
  },
  {
    "customer": {
      "emailAddress": "test33@gmail.com"
    },
    "recommendationProductDetails": [{
      "productId": "3333",
      "title": "Title 33",
      "imageWebAddress": "http://url.com/GetImage/333",
      "webAddress": "http://url.com/",
      "description": "Description 333"
    }, {
      "productId": "1111",
      "title": "Title 111",
      "imageWebAddress": "http://url.com/GetImage/111",
      "webAddress": "http://url.com/",
      "description": "Description 111"
    }]
  }
  ];
```

That i need to convert to look like this

```
jsonData = [{
    "emailAddress": "test@gmail.com"
    "productId": "4288",
    "title": "Title 1",
    "imageWebAddress": "http://url.com/GetImage/2956",
    "webAddress": "http://url.com/",
    "description": "Description 23"
}, {
    "emailAddress": "test@gmail.com"
    "productId": "8888",
    "title": "Title 8",
    "imageWebAddress": "http://url.com/GetImage/2333",
    "webAddress": "http://url.com/",
    "description": "Description 55"
}, {
    "emailAddress": "test33@gmail.com"
    "productId": "3333",
    "title": "Title 33",
    "imageWebAddress": "http://url.com/GetImage/333",
    "webAddress": "http://url.com/",
    "description": "Description 333"
}, {
    "emailAddress": "test33@gmail.com"
    "productId": "1111",
    "title": "Title 111",
    "imageWebAddress": "http://url.com/GetImage/111",
    "webAddress": "http://url.com/",
    "description": "Description 111"
}];
```

I need to remove **"customer"** and **"recommendationProductDetails"** and append value **"emailAddress"** in **"recommendationProductDetails"**

Can somebody help me to map this, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use reduce

```
const arr = jsonOne.reduce((acc, rec) => ([...acc, ...rec.recommendationProductDetails.map(it =>({ ...rec.customer, ...it }))]), [])
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flatMap

```js
const res = arr.flatMap(e =>
    e.recommendationProductDetails.map(r => ({...e.customer, ...r}))
);
console.log(res);
```

```html
<script>
const arr = [{
    "customer": {
        "emailAddress": "test@gmail.com"
    },
    "recommendationProductDetails": [{
        "productId": "4288",
        "title": "Title 1",
        "imageWebAddress": "http://url.com/GetImage/2956",
        "webAddress": "http://url.com/",
        "description": "Description 23"
    }, {
        "productId": "8888",
        "title": "Title 8",
        "imageWebAddress": "http://url.com/GetImage/2333",
        "webAddress": "http://url.com/",
        "description": "Description 55"
    }]
},
    {
        "customer": {
            "emailAddress": "test33@gmail.com"
        },
        "recommendationProductDetails": [{
            "productId": "3333",
            "title": "Title 33",
            "imageWebAddress": "http://url.com/GetImage/333",
            "webAddress": "http://url.com/",
            "description": "Description 333"
        }, {
            "productId": "1111",
            "title": "Title 111",
            "imageWebAddress": "http://url.com/GetImage/111",
            "webAddress": "http://url.com/",
            "description": "Description 111"
        }]
    }
];
</script>
```

Comment: Yes it does. If it doesn't work for you in the browser, it's time to update

Comment: Property 'flatMap' does not exist on type '